# Validating Access project number field via VBA and regex

Tags: regex, ms-access, vbscript, vba

I want to validate entries into a textbox in my Access form.  The field behind the textbox stores project number(s) that identify each project record.  We currently have a very complicated Do While loop within the textbox's before_update event that successfully validates things, but I'm working on tightening up our code and would like to understand how to do a more elegant regex validation.  Here's the technical details.

Project numbers have a standard format, such as PJ17-14-000, broken into three blocks, separated by dashes.  Here are the rules for each block.

The first block is the project type/fiscal year block.  The first two characters are always alpha characters, and they change to reflect different high-level project types.  PJ, EL, RM, ER are some examples, but these could be any two alpha chars.  Then the next two characters are always numeric, and reflect the fiscal year within which the project started.  PJ17-14-000 started in fiscal year 2017, for instance.

The second block is simply a number indicating the sequence in which projects were established.  So PJ17-1-000 is the first PJ project started in fiscal year 2017.  PJ17-2-000 is the second.  And so on.  There is no theoretical limit to the number of digits in this number, but practically it never exceeds four digits.  *But, and this is important, the leading digits can never be zero.*  So we never would use a project number such as PJ17-01-000, and the validation should reject such a number.  Instead, the analyst should enter simply PJ17-1-000.

And finally, the last block is always exactly three numeric characters that represent subprojects.  Most projects just have one part (no subprojects), and so the last block is simply 000.  But some have many subprojects, so they may have PJ17-1-001, PJ17-1-002, PJ17-1-003 (and so on) records.  For the third block, the number can (and usually does) have leading zeros.

Those are the rules for the project numbers themselves.  Here's the fun part:  Our database allows analysts to enter multiple project numbers separated by spaces into the project field.  (I know there is a better design that uses linked tables and a subform, but this is our legacy system.)  Why a project would have two numbers is a long complicated story, but sometimes (often) they do, and we have to allow for that.  So a project number field could need (and therefore should allow) an aggregate project number such as "PJ17-1-000 ER16-143-000 PI16-23-000".

So the validation should follow the rules above for any single project number, and should allow for any number of project numbers that are separated by exactly one space.  How would I do that?

I started playing around with vbscript.regexp, but couldn't figure out how to tackle this complicated problem.  Appreciate any help on how to make that work, or any other approach that you think would be elegant and easier to read/maintain than our current beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[1-9]\d*-\d+(?: [A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[1-9]\d*-\d+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://%5E[A-Z]%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B2%7D-[1-9]%5Cd*-%5Cd+(?:%20[A-Z]%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B2%7D-[1-9]%5Cd*-%5Cd%20)*$)

The single project code pattern is `[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[1-9]\d*-\d+`:

- `[A-Z]{2}` - 2 uppercase ASCII letters (NOTE: if `objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True` then this will also match lowercase ASCII letters)
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[1-9]\d*` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then 0+ any digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

The whole pattern is `^<code>(?: <code>)*$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `<code>` - the project code pattern as described above
- `(?: <code>)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - - a space
  - `<code>` - project code pattern as described above
- `$` - end of string.

VBA code:

```
Function IsProjCodeValid(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[1-9]\d*-\d+(?: [A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[1-9]\d*-\d+)*$"

    IsProjCodeValid = objRegEx.Test(s)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow that was fast!  The one thing I think might need a tweak is the code for the subproject number.  This isn't just "one or more digits."  It's exactly three digits.  So I think the tweak would be to simply change \d+ to \d{3}.  Seems to work.  That sound correct?

Comment: @EmilyFTW:  If the number of digits is always 3, yes, use `\d{3}`.